# tuple index out of range for regexp_replace - pyspark-sql

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
SELECT url, 
       regexp_replace(title, '(http|ftp|file|https)://[-a-z0-9+&@#/\%?=~_-|!:,.;/]*|\<.*?\>|(=+)\s*(.*?)\s*(=+)|&\w+;', '') AS text_body
FROM   df_table_doc
```

```
0   https://demo.com        New Arch {Onboarding}..Lets (Onboard) it..
1   https://example.com     New Arch (Onboarding)
```

Adding the pattern `\{.*?\}` to replace anything within `{}` is failing with :

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-20460659c049> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('spark_sql', '--limit 200', "select url, regexp_replace(title, '(http|ftp|file|https)://[-a-z0-9+&@#/\\%?=~_-|!:,.;/]*|\\<.*?\\>|\\{.*?\\}|(=+)\\s*(.*?)\\s*(=+)|&\\w+;', '') as text_body\n        from df_table_doc\n")
```

Comment: Can you share sample data for `df_table_doc` in a format that is easily readable into pyspark?

Comment: Is `_-|` intended? It creates a range in the character class.

Comment: @meenaparam

The data is in json file

`
{"url":"https://demo.com","title":"https://New Arch {Onboarding}..Lets (Onboard) it.."},
{"url":"https://example.com","title":"New Arch (Onboarding)"}
`


df = spark.read.json('file.json')
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df_table_doc')
df1 = spark.sql('SELECT url, title FROM df_table_doc')

df1.show()

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew  Removed _-|, but still have the same error.

Comment: Thanks @Anand, unfortunately I'm unable to replicate your error. Instead, I get an "illegal repetition" error for the second regex (adding in the `\{.*?\}`). The first regex works fine, but I'm not sure what's wrong with the second one.